# Problems using Doctrine 2 CLI to connect to vagrant (scotchbox) database

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, vagrant

I'm attempting to use Doctrine 2 ORM for my PHP web application, and I'm running into a problem I can't figure out.

For testing I'm using Vagrant, with Scotchbox installed (installs a basic LAMP stack).

I'm trying to run $vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create and I keep getting this error:

[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: No such file or directory

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliException]
  No such file or directory

Here's my connection parameters:

```
  $isDevMode = true;
  $paths = array("db-entities/");

  $dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'mysqli',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'dbname'   => 'scotchbox'
  );

  $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
  $entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

If I add a 'host' => '127.0.0.1' to the array, I then get a different error:

[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: Connection refused

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliException]
  Connection refused

If I try and connect with a standard mysqli call, it works (DB_HOST = 'localhost'):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
  if (!$mysqli) {
    die("Database connection failed:");
  }
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong??

Comment: And if you add `'host' => 'localhost'` in the array ? I had a similar problem with 2 mysql instances on an OSX install ... Maybe check your process too.

Comment: If I add that it gives me the same error as without it.

Comment: and what a `ps waux | grep mysql` says ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may also run into this problem, here's the solution:

Simply update the Vagrantfile to use rsync:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", type: "rsync",
    rsync__exclude: ".git/"
```

Instead of the default:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
```

You will need to run `vagrant rsync` each time you want to update your virtual machine, but now you can ssh in and run the following command successfully:

```
$vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

Comment: You could probably just remove the mount options (or update them) but I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have install `php-mysql` on vagrant machine.